# Remove item in the third level of a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am trying to remove information that is in the third level of a dictionary and can only use it after the removal of this information.
But I can not, what am I doing wrong?

```
    public class Person
{
    int id;
    string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

   public List<Product> ListProd;
}

public class Product
{
    public int idProd;
    public string Description;
    public List<Tax> listTax;
}

public class Tax
{
    public int idTax;
    public string Value;
}

//Method
public void SomeMethod()
{
        Dictionary<int, List<int>> dicRemove = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
        List<int> listTaxToRemove = new List<int>();
        for (int m = 8; m < 10; m++)
        {
            listTaxToRemove.Add(m);
        }
        dicRemove.Add(10, listTaxToRemove);

        Dictionary<int, List<Person>> dic = new Dictionary<int, List<Person>>();
        List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Person d = new Person();
            d.ID = i;
            d.Name = "Person " + i;
            d.ListProd = new List<Product>();
            for (int j = 3; j < 6; j++)
            {
                Product p = new Product();
                p.idProd = j;
                p.Description = "Product " + j;
                d.ListProd.Add(p);
                p.listTax = new List<Tax>();
                for (int m = 7; m < 10; m++)
                {
                    Tax t = new Tax();
                    t.idTax = m;
                    t.Value = "Tax " + m;
                    p.listTax.Add(t);
                }
            }
            list.Add(d);
        }

        dic.Add(10, list);

        var q = dic.Select(s => s.Value
                         .Select(s1 => s1.ListProd
                              .Select(s2 => s2.listTax
                         .RemoveAll(r =>!dicRemove[s.Key].Contains(r.idTax))))).ToList();

}
```

I tried a number of ways, through iterations, this approach had just deleting unnecessary records.

Thank you!

Comment: Always add a programming language tag!

Comment: @KnD182, can you leave a feedback on my answer, please? does it solve you issue or not?

Answer (score 0):

`RemoveAll` is not invoked due to deferred execution of `Select`

you have 3 `Select` and only one `ToList()`

`q` has type `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[System.Int32]]]`

there are nested `IEnumerable` object which were not enumerated

here is a working variant **but absolutely unreadable, don't do it like this**

```
var q = dic.Select(s => s.Value.Select(s1 => s1.ListProd.Select(s2 => s2.listTax.RemoveAll(r=>!dicRemove[s.Key].Contains(r.idTax)))
                                                        .ToList())
                               .ToList())
        .ToList();
```

improved variant

```
foreach(var pair in dic)
    foreach(var person in pair.Value)
        foreach(var prod in person.ListProd)            
            prod.listTax.RemoveAll(t=>!dicRemove[pair.Key].Contains(t.idTax));
```